# array_merge(): Argument #1 is not an array

Tags: php, json, api, curl, array-merge

need your help on this... got an error on my array_merge
here's my code:

```
//first
    $url1="https://www.zopim.com/api/v2/chats";
    $ch1 = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_URL, $url1);
    curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
    curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $output1 = curl_exec($ch1);
    $info1 = curl_getinfo($ch1);
    curl_close($ch1);

    $chats1 = json_decode($output1,true);

    //second
    $url2="https://www.zopim.com/api/v2/chats?page=2";
    $ch2 = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_URL, $url2);
    curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
    curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $output2 = curl_exec($ch2);
    $info2 = curl_getinfo($ch2);
    curl_close($ch2);

    $chats2 = json_decode($output2,true);



    $r = [];
    if(is_array($chats1) && is_array($chats2))
    {
        foreach($chats1 as $key => $array)
        {
            $r[$key] = array_merge($chats2[$key], $array);
        }
    }
    else
    {
    echo 'problem with json';
    }
    echo json_encode($r, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

I need to combine a two json using array_merge()... im using curl authorization to call my API..

but when i try to run the code it has a error:
[image]

here's number 44 error:
[image]

Comment: Don't know which is line 42, but it would seem that one of your two output variables does not contain an encoded object or array.

Comment: Which one is line 42?

Answer (score 1):

This means your `json_decode` fails. It will fail if the string is no valid JSON. When it fails json_decode returns either null or false, so you have to check if the response is valid:

```
$chats1 = json_decode($output1, true);
$chats2 = json_decode($output2, true);

if ($chats1 && $chats2 && is_array($chats1) && is_array($chats2)) {
    // your code goes here
}
```

Comment: That is not completely true, this will still fail if the json contains only a double quoted string (valid json).

Comment: Added is_array check

Comment: Then the problem is on another place?